# Python Development Module Path

Tags: python, git

While developing an app and working within the apps local git clone directory I have set up a link to the development version (within its git clone dir) of a module.  I do this so that any running of the app, from within the development dir, calls the development version of the module (which is usually being developed on at the same time).  I just add a .gitignore for the mymodule.py and this works.

But I don't like this.  So I've been trying to figure out a way to make the mymodule.py pull from the development path rather than the python module path where the released version is installed.  Anyone doing something like this or have a suggestion.

```
 dev/myapp/myapp -> import mymodule
   -from here-
 dev/mymodule/mymodule.py
   -not here-
 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mymodule.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to follow up on what @forivall said, I believe `virtualenv` will solve your problems.

You can create a development environment, and install all dependencies inside of it.  This should make it so you don't have to manually manipulate your python path.

1. `virtualenv /path/to/env/` - will create a new env
2. after that you need to 'activate' your env `source /path/to/env/bin/activate`

Now you are using a seperate clean python environment.  You can checkout your dependencies and or install them using `pip` directly from git!!!  If using settuptools you can create a development egg which [seems to address your exact problem](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode).

Comment: So this sets up a virtualenv say myvs in a directory ./myvs which is cool starting point.  But is there a way to add a dir to the PATH of this virtualenv?

Comment: when you use `sys.path.append` it should be adding to the path to your activated virtualenv, not your system python install.

Comment: Like I said to @forivall wow I like virtualenv and I'm using it now in this apps development.  However your sys.path.append got me thinking and I ultimately just used a 'if os.path.basename(os.getcwd())==PrgName:sys.path.insert(0,DevPathToMyModule) prior to the import mymode call

Comment: can you run `settuptools`? it is quite easy to create a `setup.py` file for your project, which will allow you to run `python setup.py develop` which automatically creates a development version of your app and puts it on your pythonpath, without any need to manually manipulate your PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `virtualenv`. Google it.

If it's too much work, you can also use `virtualenvwrapper`, which more simply manages your `virtualenv`s.

Comment: I just read through https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv and I'm not sure how this works?  Do you have an example?

Comment: I found this and it was a good walk through http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/

Answer (score 1):

You could set the [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environmental variable to specify the order that different locations are checked in. Just put your development version first.

Comment: So you just adjust PYTHONPATH while developing?  I wouldn't want to this to be a global PYTHONPATH because if the app is run outside of the development dir I want the installed version of the module to run.

Comment: You can do it at the same time `PYTHONPATH=BLAH python somefile.py`. I usually end up having my makefile set that for me and then i do something like "make dev" or something to start the dev environment one. `virtualenv` sounds like a good answer, too.